# Regex field validation producing false (?) negative

Tags: forms

I've also asked [this question in the module issues](https://www.drupal.org/node/2605466), since I'm not sure if it is a bug or something I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to use the Field Validation module to apply a regex control to ensure that a Philippines cell phone number is correct, and I'm getting what seems to me to be a false negative.

These numbers are 63, followed by 8 or 9, then followed by 9 digits.
I've created a control using the Regex (PCRE) rule, with the following format:

```
 ^63[8-9]\d{9}$
```

and yet it persistently gives me false negatives, for example on this: 639121129374

I can't see anything wrong with the regex, and I've tried testing my numbers on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) (cool tool) and they work fine. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the PCRE validator you need to add [delimiters](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) to your regular expression. For example:

```
/^63[8-9]\d{9}$/
```